# "Hide left navigation" option not working

Tags: bug, sidebar

Since a new sticky left navigation is out I thought that I might give it a chance, when I go to settings -> preferences and click on the **Hide left navigation** checkbox, it gives me a nice view of the desired left navigation bar.

The problem comes when I refresh the page, the navbar disappears. I've checked on the network tab from developer console and it's making the request and returning either **true** or **false** as the case may be.

I've tested in Firefox, Chrome and Safari on macOS High Sierra 10.13.5 and it's happening on the three browsers.

Here are a couple of images showing the response

[image: chrome]

Chrome 67.0.3396.87 (Build oficial) (64 bits)

[image: firefox]

Firefox Quantum 60.0.2 (64-bit)

---

Here's a GIF of the issue:

[image: everyone gets a gif]

**Am I being punished for not trusting the left navbar from the beginning?**

Comment: Can't reproduce on Chrome Version 67.0.3396.87 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10.

Comment: Wait one. I can reproduce it, here's how: Have two tabs with SO in them, both with hidden left nav. In one tab, open preferences and set it to show the left nav. Click the logo or whatever, get back to the homepage, refresh, left nav displays. Go to your other page and refresh. Note that the left nav remains hidden. Go back to your original tab and refresh, now the left nav is hidden again. Maybe a cookie thing?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan wow! I've always have several SO tabs open that may be the reason, but the **Disable top bar stickiness** option works like a charm even if I refresh the window and I think both work with a cookie. Anyway I'm going to try testing with all my tabs closed

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan nope, it's still happening even with the only tab being the SO settings. I'm pretty sure is a cookie thing but the strange thing is that the bar stickiness option is working

Comment: Well, the left nav thing is new; they might be using an alternate method for it since it's not "baked in" yet. Anyway, let's see what the SO team comes up with.

Comment: @KacosPro SE doesn't use cookies for these preferences. The preferences are stored in SE's database, which is a separate database per site (which is why cross-site preferences are difficult). You can test it. If it's a cookie, then the pref. would apply only to the browser in which you set it & won't pass between two browsers/profiles (even on the same machine). If it's stored in their database, then the preference is applied wherever you're logged in (different browsers, different machines/devices, etc.). Basically, cookies are scoped only to the browser/profile in which they are set.

Comment: @Makyen oh I see! although I remember somewhere seeing a top bar cookie. I think I'm being punished then :(

Comment: I, also, happened to play with this setting today. In the brief time I tried it, I was not able to get the chosen selection to persist across page refresh. So, basically, it appears the data is not being correctly stored in the database. However, it really wasn't that much of an issue for me because my preferred usage is to have the left-sidebar not displayed. Given that I don't want to have to make this selection in every single SE site, I created [Left-sidebar in the Topbar](//stackapps.com/questions/7928), a userscript which puts the left-sidebar in the topbar on all SE sites.

Comment: I hope it's not because they were trying to reload only the inner content instead of loading the whole page including top bar and that menu :)

Comment: Most evil way to make it disappear. Mark the div as an ad with adblock =)

Comment: [Related on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311548/369403). Try changing the setting there.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I did try there, for me it doesn't work either

Comment: This is sooooo annoying, whenever I switch from SO to Meta.SO, I loose the left nav. I mean I hate the left nav, but not having any nav is even worse. Right now I do not have any nav after visiting Meta once.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Can you post this information as an answer? Comments can sometimes be prone to deletion.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce it on Chrome Version 67.0.3396.87 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10, here's how:

- Have two tabs with SO in them, both with hidden left nav.
- In one tab, open preferences and set it to show the left nav.
- Click the logo or whatever, get back to the homepage, refresh, left nav displays.
- Go to your other page and refresh.
- Note that the left nav remains hidden.
- Go back to your original tab and refresh, now the left nav is hidden again.

My first guess is they're using a cookie for tracking this feature until it's fully tested, but I could be (and likely am) completely wrong.

[As @Mayken mentions in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369974/hide-left-navigation-option-not-working?noredirect=1#comment602868_369974), they usually use the database to store these kinds of settings, so it could be that it's either not saving the change, or not reading it correctly.